# How to update JavaFX canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I've been working on a GUI for visualizing the layout and working of a basic neural network program that I have been developing and figured the best way would be via JavaFX canvas. Each cycle, the program clears the screen then redraws the status using

```
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
gc.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
gc.strokeLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

to draw the nodes (ovals) and connections (lines) in the correct places. However, instead of updating the display with each iteration as I would expect, the canvas remains blank until all iterations are completed and there is no more drawing being performed on the canvas.

How do I make the canvas update as it is being drawn onto (ie; changing when the data changes) instead of once all drawing is completed?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you doing everything on the JavaFX application thread without giving JavaFX time to redraw the GUI?

Comment: The calculations (eg; back propagation) are done on a separate thread.The drawing is done on the main thread, as far as I am aware it is not possible to draw onto the canvas on a different thread?

Comment: I've modified my code so that the calculation processing is done in a separate thread, and the drawing is done using an animation timer. This still hasn't fixed the issue, and the content is only displayed after the thread has finished its looping of training data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my thread was not set up properly and so was suspending further processing in the thread that called it until completed.